# Why do I get 2, 5, 8, 11 in the Triangle column instead of 3, 6, 9, 12 when I use the ChainLadder package?

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'origin': ['200101', '200105', '200203', '200204', '200310', '200311'],
    'development': ['200103', '200207', '200206', '200301', '200312', '200405'],
    'value': [100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350]
})

# Convert DataFrame to Triangle
triangle = cl.Triangle(df, origin='origin', development='development', columns='value', cumulative=False)

triangle_new = triangle.grain("OQDQ")

triangle_new
```

```
    2   5   8   11  14  17  20  23  26  29  32  35  38  41
2001Q1      100.00                                              
2001Q2                      150.00                              
2001Q3                                                      
2001Q4                                                      
2002Q1          200.00                                          
2002Q2              250.00                                      
2002Q3                                                      
2002Q4                                                      
2003Q1                                                      
2003Q2                                                      
2003Q3                                                      
2003Q4      300.00  350.00                                          
2004Q1                                                      
2004Q2
```

I am expecting the column names are 3, 6, 9, 12, ..., quarterly. How can I fix this?